# Data Type Encompassing Two Sum Types?

Tags: idris

Given these 2 sum types:

```
data Foo = A Int | B String
data Bar = C Int | D String
```

I'd like to define a function that returns `Either (Foo or Bar) String`.

So, I attempted to make:

`data Higher = Foo | Bar`

But it failed to compile:

```
*ADT> :r
Type checking ./ADT.idr
ADT.idr:3:6:Main.Foo is already defined
ADT.idr:4:6:Main.Bar is already defined
```

How can I create a `Higher` data type, which consists of `Foo` or `Bar`?

Comment: Why not just `Either (Either Foo Bar) String`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can indeed!

```
data Foo = A Int | B String
data Bar = C Int | D String

data Higher : Type where
    InjFoo : Foo -> Higher
    InjBar : Bar -> Higher
```

Now you can do `InjFoo (B "Hello")` or `InjBar (C 5)`.

Comment: Does Idris have co-products, per https://www.reddit.com/r/scala/comments/4g43js/union_types_in_scala/d2fimz5?